# UICollectionView animate cell image when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a menu bar created with `UICollectionView` in my App. I want to do animation on a selected Cell. Now i am just changing the image on the selected cell by overriding `isSelected` in `collectionViewCell` class. How can i do a animation like in this image on bottom. Any helps will be appreciated.

Image of my menu bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you want to animate (eg: with a fading) the transition between two images, when you change the image (in your `isSelected`) you might use this code:

```
UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
// change the image
}
```